# Having at least one-nonwhitespace

Tags: regex

`str` must be true if it has at least one non-whitespace enclosed in the parenthesis:

```
str = (a)
str = ( as bs)
str = (as e)
```

and false if it has non-whitespace at all

```
str = (   )
```

Im not sure if i can do that `+` but this condition is also passing the 0 non-whitespaces. Correct it please.

```
/^\([\S+\s*]+\)$\.test(str)/
```

Comment: do you mean *at least one non-whitespace* in first line?

Comment: You're escaping the last parenthesis but not the first.

Comment: You mean the opposite, must be true when there is at least one non-whitespace and false when all whitespace ?

Comment: it works in my code, i think it is only intended for js?

Comment: @fireflieslive. that link I gave is for JS only. Check it out. If it's working in your code, which I doubt, then it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/^\(.*\S.*\)$/.test(str)
```

This matches any character, then a *non-whitespace* character (that makes it at least one non-whitespace character), and then any character till the end.

Comment: I'm confused by this. Wouldn't the first .* match the entire string, and then there will be no characters left to match the \S and it will fail. Or do I just not know how regex works? Is it doing some kind of implicit look-ahead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^\((?!\s*\)).+\)$
```

This matches an open parentheses `(` and then it fails if it is followed just by whitespaces and a `)`, or it accepts the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming str must satisfy TRUE and FALSE and nesting is implicitly not allowed

```
 ^(?:[^()]*\([^\S()]*[^\s()][^\S()]*\))+[^()]*$
```

expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [^()]* 
      \(
          [^\S()]* 
          [^\s()] 
          [^\S()]* 
      \)
 )+
 [^()]* 
 $
```